How can I use an Angular Material chckbox without additional spacing?
I'm currently working with Angular Material and would like to know if there is a way to use the checkbox without the default spacing. I noticed that Angular Material's checkbox are surrounded by some spacing by default (as seen in the image). Is there an easy way to remove this spacing so that I can insert the checkbox directly into my content without additional spacing?
<mat-checkbox formControlName="rememberMe"><span class="remember-me">Remember me</span></mat-checkbox>


padding:0 did not help.
Also this did not work:
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

Thanks in advance for your assistance

We can use the below CSS
The CSS focuses on removing the padding, height and width to the desired size and absolute positioning of the background also!
::ng-deep .custom-checkbox > div > div.mdc-checkbox {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

::ng-deep
  .custom-checkbox
  > div
  > div.mdc-checkbox
  > .mat-mdc-checkbox-touch-target,
::ng-deep
  .custom-checkbox
  > div
  > div.mdc-checkbox
  > .mdc-checkbox__native-control {
  height: 18px !important;
  width: 18px !important;
}

::ng-deep
  .custom-checkbox
  > div
  > div.mdc-checkbox
  > .mdc-checkbox__background {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

Is it bad if you use ng-deep because it is deprecated?

How did you know you needed these CSS selectors? I'm asking so I can find out for myself next time.

@coder right click open inspector, then top left there will be a button to select a element, then on the right side you will see the styles applied, modify the styles to achieve your desired result!
